# How to prevent malicious operations from virtual keyboard in UWP app

Tags: uwp, keyboard, virtual, kiosk-mode, piracy-prevention

I'm writing a UWP app that will run in kiosk mode on Windows 10.
Unfortunately, the virtual keyboard always shows the settings' key:

[image: Default virtual keyboard showing settings' key]

I can't figure out how I can hide it.
The problem is that malicious users use it to change system settings, making the kiosk unusable.

How can I prevent these malicious operations? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: it's by-design, currently there is not good way to hide the setting button for virtual keyboard.  For this scenario, we suggest post your requirement with windows feed back hub app.